# what does 'mission leather chair' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Instantly a dozen dog voices began to shake the roof. While they bayed and howled and yapped I looked at a small alcove office with a rolltop desk and a waiting room with **mission leather chairs** and three diplomas on the wall, at a mission table scattered with copies of the Dog Fancier's Gazette.

It's from Raymond Chandler's "The man who like the dogs."

What does 'mission leather chair" really mean?

Does it have something to do with 'missionary works'?

But it wouldn't make much sense if it is so.

Comment: Search Google images for "mission leather chair" and tell me if that didn't answer your question. :)

Comment: It's just a kind of [office chair](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mission+leather+chair%22&tbm=isch)

Comment: @NVZ Not much help, rather misleading, time wasting. Instead, look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_style_furniture

Comment: OP, ignore the *leather* part, which is just an extra adjective. The link I provided above may help.

Comment: @Kris I agree that the wiki link is better. *Leather* or not, the furniture is of "mission style"

Comment: @NVZ Technically, this post is GR. The answer is given in good detail on Wikipedia, which is one of the first sources one would look for, for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mission** is a style of furniture. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_style_furniture) says:

> The word mission references the Spanish missions throughout colonial California, though the design of most Mission Style furniture owed little to the original furnishings of these missions.

Here's that Google Image Search: https://www.google.com/search?q=mission+leather+chair